# Remove space between text overflow ellipsis and subsequent text

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS code which displays some text that is cut off with text-overflow: ellipsis, then following that there's some extra text:

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

.after {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</span>
<span class="after">after</span>
```

This trims the text fine:

[image]

[image]

However, as you can see, when the window is resized the space between the ellipsis and "after" is not consistent. Is there any way I can make sure that "after" is always right next to the ellipsis with HTML/CSS, or even using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in `display: flex;` wrapper. Code example below.

Also, I have added `&nbsp;` before "after" text which is just shurtcode for blank space, just to ensure, there will always be space between "Lorem ipsum" text and "after" text

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

.after {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  </span>
  <span class="after">&nbsp;after</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the "display: flex" does in this case, could you please explain? Also, adding the &nbsp does add spacing before the "after", but the spacing still varies slightly if you resize the width of the window. I'd like to keep that spacing consistent regardless of the resizing.

Answer (score 0):

As you have set width: 50%, it consume that space in full width, I have set max-width to the content so text after ellipsis will be after it only on window resize.

```css
.text {
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: fit-content;
    width: 50%;
}

.after {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</span>
<span class="after">after</span>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the ellipsis at all with this code, for any window size. I'd like the ellipsis to still cut off the text, but "after" should be on the same line as the other text regardless of window size. The space I'm trying to get rid of is the space between the ellipsis and "after" in my original images (sorry they're kinda hard to see, but there is a difference between the two images)

Comment: I have updated the code.Is it that you need?

Comment: It seems to be functioning the same as my original code (or did I miss something?)

Comment: Do we any upper DOM of span that has any kind of width? This can be fixed if we used width in px. but might not be a good option. so if we have parent DOM with particular width then we can devide child's space and "after". text will appear after ellipsis

Comment: In my actual app, I do have a parent element but its width is ultimately relative to the viewport (e.g. 90% of viewport width).

Comment: So I have work around it and I tried https://jsfiddle.net/uybvgqz4/ . Let's jump on chat if requires.